# WCF over HTTPS Basic Authentication with LDAP

Tags: https, ldap, basic-authentication

I'm currently working on building a WCF web Service, I was asked to use Basic Authentication over HTTPS and also to validate whether the user is present in an LDAP group for Authorization.

I searched in Internet and it is said that Active Directory Authentication is not available in IIS and we should use our own Custom Basic Authentication Module or UserNamePasswordValidator.
[Link I used for coding Custom Authentication Module](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-6-custom-basic-authentication.aspx)
I have hosted the WCF in local IIS with SSL and now it is running under https.

The question is, If I implement this one, I need to add the Authorization header manually it seems. Is there any other way I can get the User Name or Password entered in the Basic Authentication dialog which is showed when we open the service in a browser ?.

OR
could you please provide an advice on what are the things I need to do to implement the above said Security ?
I'm helpless and requesting your help on this !!!!. Thanks in Advance.

Background:
I also tried UserNamePasswordValidator, but it was doing at the Application level, I was able to view the wsdl file (Meta data of the web service without even providing credentials) so I did went with the Custom Basic Authentication Module.

With Custom Basic Authentication Module , it is asking for credentials before the svc is opened in browser. So I think this would best suite. Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic authentication works by the web server returning a 401.0 status code AND a WWW-Authenticate response header with the value 'Basic real="xxx"' where the realm is simply information shown to the user so that they understand what is asking for the authentication. When the browser receives this type of response, it displays a dialogue box to the user asking for a username/password. The browser then re-submits the originally requested URL, but also includes an 'Authorization' header whose value is a base64 encoded string which includes the username and password.

A custom authentication module for IIS basically has to handle this interaction. For each request that comes in, it needs to see if there is an 'Authorization' header, and if so, it extracts the username/password, authenticates them in whatever fashion it likes, and if successful sets up the Context.User. If there is no 'Authorization' header, or the username/password are not valid, then the module must set the response code to 401.0, and ensure that there is a WWW-Authenticate header (as described above).

In order to use the module, all other authentication modules in IIS must be disabled (although there seem to be some circumstances in which the anonymous authentication module should be enabled). Due to caching in IIS, don't be surprised if not all requests are passed to your authentication module.